# Adding Query to Titanium

Tags: javascript, sql, json, titanium

I am using Titanium for listing the number of quantities available in the particular product and I am using the Query 
"SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity)FROM mobile_product GROUP BY product_name"..

I am confused in implementing this query to Titanium JS.

My Titanium code is

---

```
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
sendit.open('GET', 'http://localhost/mobileapp/productread.php');
sendit.send();


sendit.onload = function(){
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

var json = json.mobile_product;

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker();
// turn on the selection indicator (off by default)
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

var data = [];
var pos;
for (pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++) {
data.push (Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:''+ json[pos].product_name +    '',custom_item:'b'}));
}
picker.add(data);
currentWin.add(picker);

//var rw = db.execute("SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity)FROM mobile_product    GROUP BY product_name");

picker.addEventListener("change", function(e){
Ti.API.info(''+ json[pos].product_name + '');
})
};
```

---

PLease some one help me how could I use this query in this code... I am using JSON to parse from PHPMyAdmin.....

Comment: Can some one help me out on this?????????

Comment: commenting won't help you. Is this titanium desktop?

Answer (score 0):

After rereading your question you are really asking several key pieces here.  You are asking how do I get my data into a database and then how do I execute a query against that database.

Create a Database:

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('MyDatabase');
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [mobile_product](id INTEGER, product_name TEXT, product_quantity INTEGER');
db.close();
```

Load a Database:

```
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

for(var i=0; json.length; i++){
 var product = json[i];
 addProductToDatabase(product);
}

function addProductToDatabase(_args){
  var db = Ti.Database.open('MyDatabase');
  var result = db.execute('INSERT INTO mobile_product(product_name, product_quantity) VALUES (?, ?)', _args.product_name, _args.product_quatity);
  db.close();

}

result = db.execute("SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity)FROM mobile_product GROUP BY product_name");
var myList = [];
while(result.isValidRow()){
  myList.push({
    product_name: result.fieldByName('product_name'),
    product_quantity: result.fieldByName('product_quantity')
  }];
  result.next();
}
result.close();
db.close();

var data = [];
for (i=0; i<myList.length; i++) {
 data.push (Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:''+ myList[i].product_name + '',custom_item:'b'}));
}
picker.add(data);
```

Comment: I am not talking about the local DB... I have a DB in PHPMyAdmin (remote DB) and wanna execute the query by JSON parsing and retrieve data when i change the picker....

Comment: If you want to execute a query against a database using Titanium as the question says, this is how you would do it.  If you want to execute a query on a server that returns a result set from a server NOT running Titanium, but in fact using PHP likely running on a web server, that would be a completely different question.